# Issues with R markdown, and getting packages

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, plyr

Hi I am having issues with my code-

I input the code-

```
library(reshape)
library(plyr)
asn12<-melt(asn1,id="DATE")
asn12<-rename(asn12, "inflation=value", "Province=variable")
head(asn12)
```

and keep getting the error message:

```
Error in mapvalues(x, from = names(replace), to = replace, warn_missing = warn_missing) : `from` and `to` vectors are not the same length.`
4. stop("`from` and `to` vectors are not the same length.")
3. mapvalues(x, from = names(replace), to = replace, warn_missing = warn_missing)
2. revalue(names(x), replace, warn_missing = warn_missing)
1. rename(asn12, "inflation=value", "Province=variable")
```

I have reshape, ply and dplyr installed.

However, my ply and dplyr say

> Attaching package: ‘plyr’
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:reshape’:
>
> rename, round_any

Please help

Comment: Hi, the messages on the packages are ok. the problem is in how you are specifying the `replace` parameter in `rename` function. It requires a named vector. Like `replace=c(value="inflation", variable="Province")`

Comment: Please update your question title so that it summarizes the question. It is currently pretty generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you are specifying the replace parameter in `rename` function. The messages regarding the packages are normal... The `rename` function requires a named vector.
Something like replace=c(value="inflation", variable="Province")... Possibly, you need to modify your line 4 with:

```
asn12<-rename(asn12, replace=c(value="inflation", variable="Province"))
```